# Trouble from transfer data between workers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am developing a multithreading application from Flash. To transfer data between Workers I need custom class.

```
package Klassy_obshchikh_komponentov.MultithreadingSupport 
{
    [RemoteClass(alias="Klassy_obshchikh_komponentov.MultithreadingSupport.CalcDataContainer")]
    public class CalcDataContainer 
    {
        public function CalcDataContainer(schemeXmlModel:int = 453)
        {
            this.schemeXmlModel = schemeXmlModel;
        }

        public var schemeXmlModel:int;
    }
```

And I register it from application:

```
registerClassAlias(
"Klassy_obshchikh_komponentov.MultithreadingSupport.CalcDataContainer", CalcDataContainer);
```

But when I transfer:

```
worker.setSharedProperty("interrelationContainer", interrelationContainer);
var fake = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("interrelationContainer") as CalcDataContainer;
```

variable fake is null. If I get variable without type cast - gets object with properties like my class, but class is Object78954. I think trouble is from deserializing? but how fix it?